# ReportViewer with BusinessObject datasource shows an empty table

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have followed the tutorial found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692(v=VS.100).aspx)

The only difference is that I am designing a Windows Form application.

I was able to see the Merchant datasource and I designed the report the way I like it. I also made sure that the Form1.frm has a ReportViewer which has its report pointing to the report I designed.

When I run the program, the report viewer shows me the designed report (I can see the column names), but there are no rows.

Although, I made sure to create some template `Product` instances in the `Merchant` object, as described in the tutorial, not a single `Product` was displayed.
I re-designed the report so that it does not group/sum/count anything, just list all `Products` as is, but still, I only get the column names, and now data rows.

I thought, maybe I need to instantiate a new `Merchant` object at run-time and pass it along to the `ReportViewer.LocalReport`, but I found no way to do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check your tags... It's either c#, asp or vb. Then provide more useful examples such as the code for the report and a designer screenshot of the report.

Comment: @Jaxedin Thanks. I fixed that. Also, answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I needed to do in order for me to populate the data table in the report.

I used `Product` class to build the dataset used to design the report

```
// the following code is copied from the tutorial pointed at my question.
// I just reduced it to the basics to make the answer short and simple
public class Product {
    private string m_name;
    private int m_price;

    public Product(string name, int price) {
        m_name = name;
        m_price = price;
    }
}

public class Merchant {
    private List<Product> m_products;

    public Merchant() {
        m_products = new List<Product>;
        m_products.Add(new Product("Pen",25));
        m_products.Add(new Product("Pencil",30));
        m_products.Add(new Product("Notebook",15));
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
         return m_products;
    }
}
```

All I needed to do at run time was to change the `DataSource` of the databindingsource, and that should do the trick:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      Merchant merchant = new Merchant();  // Instantiate a new instance of Merchant
      // by now merchant already has a List of 3 Products


     //Call getProducts() to fetch a List of 3 Products and pass it
     // to the binding datasource used to design the report
     this.ProductBindingSource.DataSource = merchant.getProducts();


     //added by default (by the wizard)
     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```